# KineticJS click on right side of Rect not working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, kineticjs

In Chrome, the following looks okay when drawn, and click on the Rect works most of the time, but clicking near the right-hand side of the rectangle does not seem to work. Any ideas?  (Modify "./_js/library" to point to your copy of KineticJS).

Firefox and IE10 seem to be okay.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="./_js/library/kinetic-v5.0.0.js"></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>

   var OnLoad = function(){
    var kstage = new Kinetic.Stage(   {'container':'divContainer' ,'width':800 ,'height':200}   );
    var klayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    var krect  = new Kinetic.Rect( {'fill':'#DDFFDD' ,'x':0 ,'y':0 ,'width':790 ,'height':100} );
    krect.on(   'click'   ,function(a){ 
      jQuery('#divResult').text( 'Clicked: '+ kstage.getPointerPosition().x ); 
    });
    klayer.add( krect  );
    kstage.add( klayer );
   }
   jQuery(window)['load']( OnLoad );
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="divContainer" width=800 height=200 style="border:1px solid #FF0000"></div>
  <div id="divResult">Hello</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI: Turned out to be a bug in KineticJS that has now been fixed.